# Which part of the class name is a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails project I have the class:

```
class Police::Office 
end
```

Now I create an Interactor in the same namespace:

```
class Police::Office::ConstructInteractor 
end
```

**1. Is this allowed or can it provoke name clashes?**

**2. What is `Police::Office::ConstructInteractor`?**

Is it a class in a module like:

```
module Police::Office
  class ConstructInteractor 
  end
end
```

Or a class in a class?

```
class Police::Office
  class ConstructInteractor 
  end
end
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1. Is this allowed**

Of course it is allowed. Classes are allowed to contain constants. (BTW: it would have taken you only a couple of seconds to try it out yourself.)

> **or can it provoke name clashes?**

I have no idea what that means, but again, you can easily test it out yourself by just copy&pasting the code you posted and run it.

> **2. What is `Police::Office::ConstructInteractor`?**
>
> Is it a class in a module like:
>
> ```
> module Police::Office
>   class ConstructInteractor 
>   end
> end
> ```

Of course not. You defined `Police::Office` to be a class earlier, so it obviously is a class.

> Or a class in a class?
>
> ```
> class Police::Office
>   class ConstructInteractor 
>   end
> end
> ```

Yes. But note that this is *not* a "class in a class". This is a *constant* in a class. In Ruby, classes don't nest like they do in Beta, gBeta, Newspeak, or Scala (not even like in Java). There is no relationship whatsoever between the class referenced by the constant `Police::Office::ConstructInteractor` and the class referenced by the constant `Police::Office`.